# Como descobrir a resposta com menor pontuação?

Tags: suporte, votos, data-explorer

Como descobrir a resposta com menor pontuação no SOPT?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eu "forkei" uma [*query* existente no Exchage Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/348976/respostas-mais-negativas) e acho que é o que você quer.

Comment: Cara, desde quando tem queries no SO?

Comment: Quase desde o início. Tem toda uma API.

Comment: Testei no SOEN. Será que está certa essa query? eu lembro de já ter visto uma resposta com o lendário `-444`

Comment: Não entendi nada desse comentário :D Mas acho que está. Muitas delas podem não ser muito prefeitas, teria que analisar todos detalhes do banco, ver se não ter nenhum *corner case*, mas em geral não se procura exatidão. Originalmente esta consulta era feita no SO, eu que puxei para o SOpt.

Comment: Alguém aproveitou sua query para dar mais negativos ainda, kkkkkk. Poxa vida!

Comment: Teve um caso mesmo :D

Comment: -10 é obra mesmo...

Answer (score 8):

Esse tipo de pesquisa não precisa do SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer), fazendo uma busca normal com a seguinte expressão dá o resultado:

```
is:answer score:..-5
```

Significa: buscar respostas de menos infinito até -5.

Para procurar as respostas com mais de 50 votos seria:

```
is:answer score:50..
```

O link de "Pesquisa Avançada" mostra as opções mais comuns para refinar a busca:


<kbd>[image]</kbd>

E a página [Como fazer uma busca? - Central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) tem todos os detalhes. <sup><sup>h/t Math</sup></sup>

Comment: Excelente! Eu sabia que tinha algo assim mas eu não conseguia encontrar. O que você acha de criarmos um tópico para reunir as possibilidades de busca "avançada" na caixa de busca?

Comment: Talvez não seja necessário: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching Apesar de que acho que traduziram mais do que deveriam, hehehe

Comment: Tinha esquecido de acrescentar a fonte de informação, gracias pela lembrança :)